# What Scheme implementation am I running?

Tags: scheme

Given a Scheme shell/interpreter, what command could output its implementation (R5RS, R6RS or whatever).

For example, I have mit-scheme installed in a Debian machine. How could I discover what implementation it is?

I'm thinking in terms of Python. If you have a Python shell, you can either run
`import sys`
`print(sys.version)`
to print the version directly, or test it with:
`print 'abc'`
to see if it runs (it would run in case of Python2).

Comment: there's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777702/how-to-detect-version-of-mit-scheme but this does not appear to be portable to e.g. racket

Answer (score 0):

> I have mit-scheme installed in a Debian machine. How could I discover what implementation it is?

From the REPL , evaluate the `(features)` function , it will display the supported SRFIs (Scheme Requests for Implementation) and more information.

The latest version is available on debian Buster : [mit-scheme (10.1.5-1)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/mit-scheme).

The second question is already answered in the comment of [@thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig).

[MIT/GNU Scheme release notes](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/release.html)